# Changing value to true onClick on object in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple todo app in which i add my "todos" and if they are done i just simply click done. Although after clicking the state is updated and the payload is being printed to the console with proper actions "TODO_DONE", done field still remains false.
my case for "TODO_DONE" in Reducer:

```
 case "TODO_DONE":
      return state.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === action.payload) {
          return {
            ...todo,
            done: true,
          };
        }
        return todo;
      });
```

i use it here:

```
<button onClick={() => doneTodo(todo)}>Done</button>
```

in the TodoList component:

```
import { deleteTodoAction, doneTodo } from "../actions/TodoActions";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
const TodoList = ({ todoss, deleteTodoAction, doneTodo }, props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Director list</h3>
      {todoss.map((todo) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div> {todo.name} </div>
            <button onClick={() => deleteTodoAction(todo)}>Usuń</button>
            <button onClick={() => doneTodo(todo)}>Done</button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todoss: state.todoss,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  deleteTodoAction,
  doneTodo,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList);
```

Ofc, the "done" value is my initial value inside TodoForm with Formik:

```
<Formik
        initialValues={{
          id: uuidv4(),
          name: "",
          date: "",
          done: false,
        }}
        onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
        enableReinitialize={true}
      >
```

Anyone knows why this doest not work?

Answer (score 1):

Check your `doneTodo` action. Since you are passing `todo` object to it. It should be `action.payload.id` instead of `action.payload`.

```
todo.id === action.payload.id
```

Comment: @learningbtw, check whether this is the issue.

Comment: Partially yes, but it works only on second click. After creating todo with done: false as initialValue and clicking once, i still get a payload in console with false, but clicking one more time and it returns a payload with done: true. Any reasons why?

Comment: @learningbtw, can you share the reducer and actions as well? It will be easy if you can create a sandbox with your issue.